# Why is $\operatorname{Hash}(x \oplus y)$ not a secure proof-of-work algorithm?

Tags: encryption, hash, collision-resistance, proof-of-work

$x$ is challenging string, $y$ is proof string. $\operatorname{H}$ is the proof-of-work (pow) function, to find a $y$ such that $H(x,y)<2^{256}/D$

1. $x ,y = \{ 0, 1 \}^{512}$
2. $\operatorname{H}(x,y) = \operatorname{SHA-256}(x \oplus y)$
3. find a $y$ such that $\operatorname{H}(x,y)<2^{256}/D$

the question is to **prove**:

If difficulty $D$ is fixed ahead of time, attacker can find $y$ with minimum of time once $x$ is published.
(the attacker can do most of the work before x is publish)

---

my intuition is that:

1. the precomputation attack is related to xor operation. for example $1101 \oplus  1111 =0101, 0000 \oplus 0101 = 0101$.
2. there is some collision before the hash funciton. $x \oplus y = x' \oplus y'$, $\operatorname{H}(x \oplus y )=\operatorname{H}(x' \oplus y')$.

I tried my best to learn some precomputation attack or preimage attack for a full day , but finally no progress. I would be very grateful if you could give some clues.

---

The link of the origin question:
https://cs251.stanford.edu/hw/hw1.pdf
(This is from Stanford course cs251 homework, but I am not an enrolled student and I learned it by myself. I tried to finish the homework and projects to make sure I understand the topic details. Besides, the work is overdue, so I think it not violate some school rules. If it is inappropriate to ask, please let me know)

Comment: How is `x` and `y` calculated and what details are sent as a "proof-of-work"? What "work" is being proven? Is `x` the "block" (to give a blockchain-specific example) and `y` the "nonce" that the user chooses to prove that "work" has been done?

Comment: I think you are right. Use blockchain as an example, x is the block message itself, (I guess it is the the header of the last/current block), it is a certain string provided by one block. y is the calculated "nounce". @James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alleged prover can pre-compute a $u$ such that $H(u)$ satisfies the condition of the proof of work.

Given a challenge $x$, the prover can output $x \text{XOR} u$ as the proof thus cheating the game.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helps me a lot. It reminds me of the introduction of a magic property of xor operation.  If $x XOR u = y$, there is $x XOR y = u$. Thank you for your help.